# Is building for win32 the same as x86 in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, visual-studio-2012, x86

So my boss asked me to test code on VS2012(x86) and VS2012(x64) redistributable package,
but when I look at the configuration `manager>platforms...` the only options on testing VS2012 are x64 and Win32.

So my question is when I build my code with Win32, is that the same as building for x86?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes.  Win32 was the name used in old versions of VS, before 64-bit processors where available.  Back when it could also build 16-bit DOS and Windows 3.x programs, Win32 distinguished targeting Windows 9x and Windows NT.

Picking "x86" would not have been a good choice back then, those 16-bit programs also ran on a x86 processor.  It only recently became synonymous with "32-bits".  They just never changed it.

Answer (score 6):

> So my question is when I build my code with Win32, is that the same as building for on x86?

Yes. In this context x86 is synonymous with Win32.